# PHP - How to search an associative array by matching the key against a regexp

Tags: php, regex, preg-grep

I am currently working on a small script to convert data coming from an external source. Depending on the content I need to map this data to something that makes sense to my application.

A sample input could be:

```
$input = 'We need to buy paper towels.'
```

Currently I have the following approach:

```
// Setup an assoc_array what regexp match should be mapped to which itemId
private $itemIdMap = [ '/paper\stowels/' => '3746473294' ];

// Match the $input ($key) against the $map and return the first match
private function getValueByRegexp($key, $map) {
  $match = preg_grep($key, $map);
  if (count($match) > 0) {
    return $match[0];
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

This raises the following error on execution:

> Warning: preg_grep(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

What am I doing wrong and how could this be solved?

Comment: How is the function called?

Comment: @u_mulder Not sure what function you are talking about. I simply execute it like so: `$this->getValueByRegexp($input, $itemIdMap);` in the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) manual order of arguments is:

```
string $pattern , array $input
```

In your code `$match = preg_grep($key, $map);` - `$key` is input string, `$map` is a pattern.

So, your call is

```
$match = preg_grep(
    'We need to buy paper towels.', 
    [ '/paper\stowels/' => '3746473294' ] 
);
```

So, do you really try to find string `We need to buy paper towels` in a number `3746473294`?

So first fix **can be** - swap'em and cast second argument to `array`:

```
$match = preg_grep($map, array($key));
```

But here comes second error - `$itemIdMap` is array. You can't use array as regexp. Only scalar values (more strictly - strings) can be used. This leads you to:

```
$match = preg_grep($map['/paper\stowels/'], $key);
```

Which is definitely not what you want, right?

The **solution**:

```
$input = 'We need to buy paper towels.';
$itemIdMap = [
    '/paper\stowels/' => '3746473294',
    '/other\sstuff/' => '234432',
    '/to\sbuy/' => '111222',
];

foreach ($itemIdMap as $k => $v) {
    if (preg_match($k, $input)) {
        echo $v . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Your wrong assumption is that you think you can find any item from array of regexps in a single string with `preg_grep`, but it's not right. Instead, `preg_grep` searches elements of array, which fit one single regexp. So, you just used the wrong function.

Comment: No, what I need to achieve is to use the key from the map as regex to match against the input string. So basically: Loop through the key=>value pair of the map and use the key as matcher for the input.

Comment: But I don't see the loop. Do you?

Comment: Since preg_grep() takes an array I imagined it being processed internally.

Comment: Thank you so much for the input. Worked as expected :thumbsup: